# Do Galilean boosts and Lorentz boosts share the same generators?

Tags: special-relativity, angular-momentum, group-theory, galilean-relativity

Gottfried and Yan's *Quantum Mechanics* introduces a generator $N$, called the boost, which generates Galileo transformations. I think in other terminology one might say $N$ generates Galilean boosts, but I think that is just terminology. It is defined as 
$$\mathbf{N}=\mathbf{P}t-M\mathbf{X}.$$
This matches the definition on Wikipedia of the [dynamic mass moment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_angular_momentum#Dynamic_mass_moment) which is part of the same bivector as Angular momentum. That makes me think that mass moment should serve as the generator of *Lorentz* boosts. Indeed,  [this Phys.SE question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/292565/) and [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformation#The_Lie_group_SO.2B.283.2C1.29) imply to me that it does, as long as $N$ is the same as $K$. So how can these two transformations have the same generator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Galilean symmetry is a symmetry of non-relativistic physics. In reality the symmetry of physics is Lorentz invariance and non-relativistic physics arises as approximation in the limit $c\rightarrow\infty$

Acting on functions $f(x^\mu)$ the generator of Lorentz boost can be written as,
\begin{equation}
K_i\equiv M_{0i}=x_0 \partial_i-x_i \partial_0=ct\partial_i+\frac{x^i}{c}\partial_t
\end{equation}
and gives Lorentz boost by exponentiation $\Lambda=e^{K_i w}$ with argument $w=\operatorname{arctanh}\,{v/c}$ known as *rapidity*.

In the limit $c\rightarrow\infty$ we get,
\begin{equation}
w\rightarrow \frac{v}{c},\quad K_i w\rightarrow K_i^{G} v,\quad K_i^G=t\partial_i
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
e^{K_i^{G}v} \begin{pmatrix}t\\\vec{x}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}t\\x+vt\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
When we consider transformations of canonical coordinate and momenta for particle it works somewhat differently - we can rewrite in that case Lorentz generator in terms of canonical variables for relativistic particle as
\begin{equation}
\tilde{K}_i=-ct p^i+\frac{x^i}{c}H
\end{equation}
So that canonical functions transform as $f(x,p)\mapsto f(x,p)+w\{f(x,p),K_i\}+\ldots$ Note that it's not just mass but *energy* that is involved in terms with $x^i$.

However for particle $H=c\sqrt{m^2c^2+\vec{p}^2}\sim mc^2+\frac{p^2}{2m}+O(1/c^2)$

Therefore we get,
\begin{equation}
\tilde{K}_i w\sim v(-t p^i+mx^i)\equiv \tilde{K}_i^G v
\end{equation}
so that on non-relativistic canonical coordinates and momenta it acts as
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}\vec{x}\\\vec{p}\end{pmatrix}\mapsto\begin{pmatrix}x+vt\\ \vec{p}+mv\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

So no, generators are not the same but they are connected through non-relativistic limit.

Comment: Under Lorentz transformations, L transforms with the Galilean generator, right? (from the wikipedia article). I would expect it to be relativistically connected to relativistic boost generator.

Comment: Does the generator of rotations have a different form in relativistic physics?

Comment: @chuck.steel What's $L$? $\Lambda$? I'm not sure what you are confused about in wiki article. Rotations are same in Lorentz and Galilei

Comment: By L I just meant angular momentum. The wikipedia article says that the relativistic version of angular momentum is a tensor whose components are L (angular momentum) and N (dynamic mass moment). N is what you call K^G. I was surprised that the generator of rotations is relativistically connected to the generator of Galilean rather than Lorentz boosts. Does my question make any more sense?

Comment: Oh, I see now. The thing is that there's this notion of "relativistic mass", basically we can define it as $E/c$ (or $H/c$ if we treat energy as Hamiltonian) Then you can write Lorentz boost generator in a way similar to Galilean one. However I look at this as another way to confuse everyone and your question proves it.